# React native maps animateToRegion doesn't work on android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

Today I faced the problem with React Native Maps. I try to use animateToRegion to show marker on the map and everything works just fine on IOS, but on android it doesn't work. I'm absolutely sure that problem is with animateToRegion. I've already tried to use it without useEffect just on button click and my `console.log('AnimateToRegion')` shows up every time when I open map but animateToRegion which goes right after console.log doesn't work on Android.

Here is my code:

```
const Map = ({navigation, route}: HomeNavigationProps<"Map">) => {
    const [destination, setDestination] = useState(undefined);
    const mapView = React.createRef();
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();
   
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('AnimateToRegion')
        if (route.params || destination){
            if(destination && route.params){
                mapView.current.animateToRegion({ // Takes a region object as parameter
                    latitude: route.params.destination.latitude,
                    longitude: route.params.destination.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.2,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.4,
                },1000);
            }
            if (route.params && !destination) {
                mapView.current.animateToRegion({ // Takes a region object as parameter
                    latitude: route.params.destination.latitude,
                    longitude: route.params.destination.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.2,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.4,
                }, 1000);
            }
            if (destination && !route.params) {
                mapView.current.animateToRegion({ // Takes a region object as parameter
                    latitude: destination.latitude,
                    longitude: destination.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.2,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.4,
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
       
    }, [isFocused]);
return (
          <MapView
                    ref={mapView}
                    mapType={satellite ? "hybrid" : "standard"}
                    style={{flex: 1}}
                    showsUserLocation={true}
                    followsUserLocation={true}
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    initialRegion={{

                                        latitude: 53.227200,
                                        longitude: 50.243698,
                                        latitudeDelta: 3,
                                        longitudeDelta: 3,
                    }}

                />
)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found out what is going on! The thing is I use string for longitude/latitude and somehow IOS can parse string but android not. I think it should be warning in this case.